# Is this a bug or a setup issue for using NewsKMeasnClustering.java

Tags: hadoop, mahout

Is this a bug or a set-up  in NewsKMeansClustering.java, an example code given in chapter 9 of Mahout-in-Action?
I was running this program against a directory of sequence files. The output error message is as follows:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File newsClusters/clustersclusteredPoints/part-m-00000 does not exist.
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:361)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:245)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getLength(FileSystem.java:676)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.(SequenceFile.java:1417)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.(SequenceFile.java:1412)
>           at mia.clustering.ch09.NewsKMeansClustering.main(NewsKMeansClustering.java:76)

The directory structure of my development environment is shown as follows as well:

> ~/workspaceMahout1/recommender/newsClusters% ls
>   canopy-centroids  clusters  df-count  dictionary.file-0  frequency.file-0  tfidf-vectors  tf-vectors  tokenized-documents  wordcount
>   ~/workspaceMahout1/recommender/newsClusters/clusters/clusteredPoints% ls
>   part-m-00000

Afterwards, I change the code from the original one

```
new Path(clusterOutput+Cluster.CLUSTERED_POINTS_DIR +”/part-m-00000”), conf);
```

to

```
new Path(clusterOutput+”/clusteredPoints”+”/part-m-00000”), conf);
```

The program can go through without giving the above error messages. I would like to know is that a bug in the original code or are there any other hidden issues?